# How to use \paragraph without seeing the title in the final pdf?

Tags: paragraphs, vim, vim-latex

I am writing a review and using Latex to create the document. Since I have to go back to many many references I want to take advantage of the folding option with each paragraph I write so I can easily refer to the paragraph title from a fully folded document for a quick idea of what is it each of them about. This is how it looks when it is folded:

```
+     23 lines: \section{Introduction}------------------------------------------
        \section{Background and literature review}
                \subsection{This is the title of the subsection}
                        \subsubsection{This is the tittle of the subsubsection}
---+   5 lines: > > > \paragraph{This paragraph is about xyz}
---+  19 lines: > > > \paragraph{This paragraph is about abc}  -----------------
---+   5 lines: > > > \paragraph{}----------------------------------------------
---+   5 lines: > > > \paragraph{}----------------------------------------------
```

This is the unfolded document. As you can see, the first two paragraph has a title while the other two don't have:

```
\subsubsection{This is the title of the subsubsection}
    \paragraph{This paragraph is about xyz}
    This is the content of the first paragraph
    \paragraph{This paragraph is about abc}
    This is the content of the second paragraph
    \paragraph{}
    This is the content of the third paragraph
    \paragraph{}
    This is the content of the fourth paragraph
```

When I make the pdf I see this:

---

This is the title of the subsubsection

**This paragraph is about xyz** This is the content of the first paragraph

**This paragraph is about abc** This is the content of the second paragraph

This is the content of the third paragraph

This is the content of the fourth paragraph

---

As you can see, the first two paragraph (that have a title between the curly brackets) shows the paragraph title before the actual paragraph while the others (with nothing within the curly brackets) show only the paragraphs. When I compile the file to pdf I wan to see only the paragraphs but still having the paragraph titles in the foldings of the .tex file for quick reference. Like this:

---

This is the title of the subsubsection

This is the content of the first paragraph

This is the content of the second paragraph

This is the content of the third paragraph

This is the content of the fourth paragraph

---

Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: you mention a "folding option" which I assume (given your tagging) that that is something in vim? anyway i assume if you don't need `\paragraph` level headings you can do `\renewcommand\paragraph[1]{\par}` so it always discards its argument.

Comment: Hi @DavidCarlisle, I have realized that in some parts I may want to use the titles. Is there a way to activate the titles only in specific paragraphs or is just better to use a \subsubsection with the "*" so it appears without the number?

Comment: You could create a custom paragraph command like `\newcommand{\hidetitlepar}[1]{\par}` and use that if you do not want the title to show. Then use the regular `\paragraph` if you do want the title to show.

Answer (score 1):

Latex-suite for Vim provides the `%%fake` marker for that use case.

From the [Latex-Suite manual](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/customizing-what-to-fold.html):

> The `%%fakesection` section is provided as a means for the user to group
>   lines into "fake" sections. In particular, it is useful to fold the
>   introduction of a section that is not part of a subsection:
>
> ```
> \section{Latex-Suite}
> %%fakesubsection Introduction
> A short introduction of the features of Latex-Suite.
> \subsection{Installation}
> Installation instructions.
> ```
>
> Without the `%%fakesubsection` the introduction would not be folded
>   separately from the section.

---

#### For the given example this means:

We use `%%fakeparagraph` instead of `%%fakesubsection` to mark each paragraph.

**Unfolded**

```
\subsubsection{This is the title of the subsubsection}                              
    %%fakeparagraph This paragraph is about xyz
    This is the content of the first paragraph
    %%fakeparagraph This paragraph is about abc
    This is the content of the second paragraph
    %%fakeparagraph
    This is the content of the third paragraph
    %%fakeparagraph
    This is the content of the fourth paragraph
```

**Folded**

```
\subsubsection{This is the title of the subsubsection}
-+     2 lines: > %paragraph This paragraph is about xyz----------------------------
-+     2 lines: > %paragraph This paragraph is about abc----------------------------
-+     2 lines: > %paragraph--------------------------------------------------------
-+     2 lines: > %paragraph--------------------------------------------------------
```

Notice how Latex-Suite will remove the `fake` and just display `paragraph` and your remarks.